# Edge browser support

Tags: watir-webdriver

Any idea if we have an official support for Edge browser using watir-webdriver api? I am able to launch Edge browser with a sample script, but I am not able to interact with elements. I tried the following code and it's failing to set the text field.

```
require 'watir-webdriver'
$browser = Watir::Browser.new 'edge'      
$browser.goto('http://www.google.com')  
$browser.text_field(:name => 'q').set "hello"

Error:
C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.48.1/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/response.rb:73:in `assert_ok': status code 501 

(Selenium::WebDriver::Error::ServerError)
        from C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.48.1/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/response.rb:34:in `initialize'
        from C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.48.1/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/common.rb:78:in `new'
        from C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.48.1/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/common.rb:78:in `create_response'
        from C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.48.1/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/default.rb:90:in `request'
        from C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.48.1/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/common.rb:59:in `call'
        from C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.48.1/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/bridge.rb:664:in `raw_execute'
        from C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.48.1/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/bridge.rb:642:in `execute'
        from C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.48.1/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/bridge.rb:229:in `switchToDefaultContent'
        from C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.48.1/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/target_locator.rb:100:in `default_content'
        from C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/watir-webdriver-0.9.1/lib/watir-webdriver/browser.rb:346:in `assert_exists'
        from C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/watir-webdriver-0.9.1/lib/watir-webdriver/elements/element.rb:561:in `ensure_context'
        from C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/watir-webdriver-0.9.1/lib/watir-webdriver/elements/element.rb:545:in `locate'
        from C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/watir-webdriver-0.9.1/lib/watir-webdriver/elements/element.rb:505:in `assert_exists'
        from C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/watir-webdriver-0.9.1/lib/watir-webdriver/user_editable.rb:32:in `clear'
        from C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/watir-webdriver-0.9.1/lib/watir-webdriver/user_editable.rb:11:in `set'
        from test.rb:6:in `<main>'
```

Comment: `Any idea if we have an official support for Edge browser using watir-webdriver api.` - That seems more like a support question for the watir developers. It may be better to reword this as just a question asking why your code isn't working in Edge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Selenium 2.48, there is an issue using the Ruby bindings (which Watir does) with Edge via the remote server. This issue has been fixed, but won't be available until Selenium 2.49 is released.

It is also worth noting that Microsoft WebDriver for Edge is still a little buggy, so you would likely be getting various other errors if you were not getting the error you are currently getting. :)